# c++ memset/sizeof weirdness with char buffer

Tags: c++, char, buffer, sizeof, memcpy

Two separate programs running nearly identical code. I'm copying an int, enum, and 4 floats into an unsigned char buffer, then reading them back out to make sure the process is correct.

The first was a simple test program that can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/muW6Siub).

It produces this output:

```
id: 10
o: 2
one: 1
two: 2
three: 3
four: 4
---
id: 10
o: 2
one2: 1
two2: 2
three2: 3
four2: 4
```

So I think to myself, OK...I can move this into the actual program. The main program can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/AB57sETg). Nearly the same right? Here's the problem: reading from the buffer back into a variable is hosed:

```
id: 1
o: 1
p1x: 1
p1y: 2
p2x: 3
p2y: 4
---
id: 1
o: 1073741824
one: 3
two: 4
three: 2.76624e+19
four: 4
```

For some reason, as the values are getting read out...memcpy changes more than one variable's value and I end up screwed:

```
memcpy(&i2,&buffer[0],4);      //sets i2 correctly to 1
memcpy(&o2, &buffer[4],4);     //sets o2 correctly to DISTANCE (enum == 1)
memcpy(&one,&buffer[8],8);     //resets o2 to 1073741824 and one to 1
memcpy(&two,&buffer[16],8);    //sets two correctly to number 2, but one to 3
memcpy(&three,&buffer[24],8);  //sets three correctly to 3, but two to 4
memcpy(&four,&buffer[32],8);   //sets three to 2.766... and four to 4

std::cout << "id: " << i2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "o: " << o2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "one: " << one << std::endl;
std::cout << "two: " << two << std::endl;
std::cout << "three: " << three << std::endl;
std::cout << "four: " << four << std::endl;
```

Changing memcpy to use sizeof() fixed it:

```
memcpy(&i2,&buffer[0],sizeof(i2));     
memcpy(&o2, &buffer[4],sizeof(o2));     
memcpy(&one,&buffer[8],sizeof(one));     
memcpy(&two,&buffer[16],sizeof(two));    
memcpy(&three,&buffer[24],sizeof(three));  
memcpy(&four,&buffer[32],sizeof(four));

----

id: 1
o: 1
p1x: 1
p1y: 2
p2x: 3
p2y: 4
---
id: 1
o: 1
one: 1
two: 2
three: 3
four: 4
```

What the heck was happening here??

Comment: It's impossible to tell without the declaration of `buffer` and its relation to the variables `i2`, `o2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are hardcoding a `float` size of 8, whereas it is likely 4.
So you get undefined behavior by reading 8 bytes from your buffer to a float.

Using `sizeof()` fixes it since it correctly returns 4.

Comment: I guess the whole "parameters (each floating-point number is 8 bytes)" comment threw me off: http://courses.washington.edu/css503/2014q2/assignment-4.html

Comment: I guess they meant double, not float - remember to accept

Comment: Yeah the instructor probably meant double...still wasted a bunch of time on it.

Comment: @PatK If they are teaching you stuff like this at school (be it a no-name cottage college or Stanford University), leave that place immediately. This is very unprofessional, wrong (both conceptually and technically) and harmful, especially if they start to teach bad practices to beginner programmers.

Comment: @PatK The example in the linked document is talking about _"floating point numbers"_, not _`float`_ and the examples clearly shows the use of  _`double`_.

Comment: @PatK Doesn't matter. `double` doesn't have to be 8 bytes wide. You should not be hard-wiring these sizes anyway.